# Django - Textarea Breaks From

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms

I have a form in Django which includes a text area. When I submit the form it is sending the request to the wrong URL. I have found that the same form without the textarea works correctly, but once the text area is included then it tries to send it to the root.

Please see the console output below, the top one is the request when the form includes the textarea:

```
   [09/Feb/2019 07:28:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 3409
   [09/Feb/2019 07:29:46] "POST /user/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
   Not Found: /
   [09/Feb/2019 07:29:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 3409
   [09/Feb/2019 07:29:53] "POST /user/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19883
   [09/Feb/2019 07:29:54] "GET /static/user/css/bootstrap.min.css.map 
   HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

When it has the text area I get "Not Found: /".

Please see the HTML code below for the two forms:

```
      <div class="row" style="padding-left:20px;">
    <form method="post" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class='form-group row'>
        <p>Register as driver:</p>
      </div>
      <div class='form-group row'>
        <label>Make: </label>{{ form.vehicle_make }}
      </div>
      <div class='form-group row'>
        <label>Model: </label>{{ form.vehicle_model }}
      </div>
      <div class='form-group row'>
        <label>Pasengers: </label>{{ form.numberofpassengers }}
      </div>
      <div class='form-group row'>
        <label>Vehicle Description: </label>{{ form.vehicle_description }}
      </div>
      <div class='form-group row'>
        <input type='submit' name="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class='form-group row'>
      <label>Make: </label>{{ form.vehicle_make }}
    </div>
    <div class='form-group row'>
      <label>Model: </label>{{ form.vehicle_model }}
    </div>
    <div class='form-group row'>
      <label>Pasengers: </label>{{ form.numberofpassengers }}
    </div>
    <input type='submit' name="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: The presence of the textarea field in HTML cannot affect where it is submitted to since that is defined by `action=""` which always means "same page". Please post your view code. The log shows a redirect (302), so there might be something in the view that triggers an incorrect condition based on the textarea value.

Comment: The second form has the same action and works, the first one doesn't. In this example I am sending to the same URL which can be done and I have done in other Django projects.

I have done some further investigation and if I hard code the textarea into the template then it produces the same error. It doesn't matter if it is a text area or input, it produces the same error. I have found that if I then change the name attribute to something different then it works.

Comment: I then went to the model and changed the name of the field to a different name, migrated it and then it gives the same issues with the different name. I have tried a complete reboot of the computer this is running on and it is still the same.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the model, form and view code here? Rebooting won't make a difference. It has to be something in the code itself.

Comment: Many thanks, looking through the model, form and view code has enabled me to find the error. In the view I had a block of code that was commented out and then realised that underneath it was returning an HTTP Response so I removed this line and it now works as intended.

Sorry, this is a user error on my part so I am happy for the question to be removed from stackoverflow. I thank the community for the help as posting on here enabled me to examine my code more thoroughly.